# Error opening file: mylaserdata.bag

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I just use the Hokuyo laser range-finder to try to make my own map following 2.2 of this website (http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#record). However, when I typed rosbag play mylaserdata.bag, it failed!!!! And the terminal displays:

```
[FATAL] [1345180506.412656994]: Error opening file: mylaserdata.bag
```

How can I deal with it? Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41665/error-opening-file:-mylaserdata.bag/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-08-16**:
Sorry if this is too obvious, but is the file mylaserdata.bag located on the same folder where you are executing "rosbag play mylaserdata.bag"? if it is not then you should provide the path to the bag file when executing rosbag play

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-16**:
In GUI, do you see the file name as mylaserdata.bag.active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to reproduce the error and for me this only occurs when the file doesn't exist.
Please navigate to the folder where the bag-file lies. e.g:

```
cd /path/to/file
```

(I don't know where this is in ur case.)

And make sure, you have read access there!
then use:

```
rosbag play mylaserdata.bag
```

Maybe ther is also a typo. (Check the name you used when recording the file)

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0